# Uniqueness of the Caratheodory derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $m,n \geq 1$, $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$. We say that $f$ is ***Caratheodory differentiable*** at $a$ if there exists $\varphi: U \to M_{mn}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\varphi$ is continuous at $a$ and such that $$f(x) = f(a) + \varphi(x)(x - a)$$ holds for all $x \in U$.

> If $f$ is Caratheodory differentiable at $a$, the value $\varphi(a)$
>   is unique.

Assume that $\varphi,\psi : U \to M_{mn}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfy the above. Define $g : U \to M_{mn}(\mathbb{R})$ by $$g(x) := \varphi(x) - \psi(x).$$
Then we have that $$g(x)(x - a) = 0$$
and thus
$$\|g(a)(x - a)\| = \|(g(a) - g(x))(x - a)\|\leq \|g(a) - g(x)\|_{\mathrm{op}}\|x-a\|$$ So $$\left\|g(a)\frac{x - a}{\|x - a\|}\right\| \leq \|g(a) - g(x)\|_{\mathrm{op}}$$ Since $g$ is continuous at $a$ we get that $$\left\|g(a)\frac{x - a}{\|x - a\|}\right\| < \varepsilon$$ whenever $x \in B_\delta(a) \setminus \{a\}$, for a sufficient small $\delta > 0$. Now in the paper I am reading, it is concluded that $$\boxed{g(a) = 0.}$$ Why is that so? How can this be formally shown?

Comment: $$\sup \Biggl\{ \biggl\lVert g(a) \frac{x-a}{\lVert x-a\rVert} \biggr\rVert : x \in B_{\delta}(a) \setminus \{a\}\Biggr\} = \lVert g(a)\rVert_{\text{op}}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. How would I show this? I mean, since $\|g(a)\|_{\mathrm{op}} := \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|g(a)\|$, it is clear, that $s \leq \|g(a)\|_{\mathrm{op}}$, where $s$ denotes the supremum on the left. Or maybe I am missing something obvious...

Comment: It's the same. $\frac{x-a}{\lVert x-a\rVert}$ runs over the whole unit sphere. For $y$ with $\lVert y\rVert = 1$, consider $x = a + \frac{\delta}{2}\cdot y$. Then $\frac{x-a}{\lVert x-a\rVert} = y$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Very nice! Thank you a lot.